# Tabbing Through Different Options on Application Close

Tags: macos

When I close an application using Cmd + Q and there are some unsaved changes on the application,  a window will pop up asking if I want to save, not save, or cancel

[image]

By default, save is the option that the cursor is focused on.  If I hit tab, the sub-focus will change to "Don't Save", but the primary focus will still stay on "Save".  Since the primary focus is still on "Save", that option is selected if I press "return" on my keyboard.

Is there a way to change the primary focus in this instance with my keyboard?

Comment: Did you try to use `Space` instead of `Enter` to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as “primary focus” on Mac OS X: what you are seeing is called a “default button” and will always be triggered by <kbd>return</kbd>.

To activate the focused button or other control, press <kbd>space</kbd> instead.

Additionally, if you find yourself unable to tab to buttons (this doesn't sound like the problem from your description, but it's a common question), you want to enable *Full Keyboard Access,* which is currently found at *System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts*.